# Yii CJuiAutoComplete data from Ajax request

Tags: autocomplete, drop-down-menu, yii

I have a task form for an application I am building which allows me to specify what contact it is assigned to.  I had set up a dependent dropdown in Yii with the following code:

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'associationType',
array('none'=>'None','contact'=>'Contact','sale'=>'Sale','account'=>'Account',
'project'=>'Project','case'=>'Case'),
                    array(
                        'ajax' => array(
                            'type'=>'POST', //request type
                            'url'=>CController::createUrl('tasks/parseType'), //url to call.
                            //Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
                            'update'=>'#auto_complete', //selector to update
                            )
                    ));
```

What I'm trying to do is use the CJuiAutoComplete widget with the dropDown specifying which array to grab.  So the drop down is selected to contacts, it should get a list of contacts etc.

Here is what I have for the CJui widget

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
                'name'=>'auto_select',
                'source' => $names,
                'options'=>array(
                    'minLength'=>'2',
                    'select'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {
                        $("#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'associationId').'").val(ui.item.id);
                        return false;
                    }',
                ),
            ));
```

The variable $names is just a placeholder for now, but in my controller method I pass it a JSON encoded array with id and name.  Controller code:

```
public function actionParseType() {
            //if(isset($_POST['TaskChild']['associationType'])){
                //$type=$_POST['TaskChild']['associationType'];
                $type='sale';
                $sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM x2_'.$type.'s';
                $cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
                $res = $cmd->queryAll();

                echo CJSON::encode($res);

            //}
}
```

Right now I'm forcing it to use "Sale" but I don't get anything when I call the method, and was wondering how I might go about fixing this.  I'm still a little new to Yii so I've been mostly reading wiki/forum posts on how these kinds of thing are done.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this in your controller action:

```
    $sql = 'SELECT people_id as id, CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) as value, first_name as label FROM people WHERE first_name LIKE :qterm ORDER BY first_name ASC';
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $qterm = $_GET['term'].'%';
    $command->bindParam(":qterm", $qterm, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result = $command->queryAll();
    echo CJSON::encode($result); exit;
```

Then you can check it by using this in your widget 'options' array: `'select'=>'js:function(event, ui) { console.log(ui.item.id +":"+ui.item.value); }'`

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  However, I do actually want the IDs for a later use.  Regardless, my IDE isn't happy with the method (though it works on my server).  The issue is that the JSON encode works either way when I just print out the values, but it doesn't feed those values into the auto-complete.

Comment: added a more complex example that is closer to yours. (fyi, the previous code had an anonymous function in the array_walk which is what your IDE might not have liked.)

Comment: Alright so that works and I get data back from the controller.  The problem is that the data isn't showing up on the auto-complete field unless I change the source to my controller action pair of the code you wrote, and I need it to be based on an ajax request.

Comment: You should be able to put the route to that controller action as a string value for "status" and it should fetch it via Ajax. I posted a full example [here](http://tech.ldg.me/2011/08/yii-auto-complete-example).